# how to perform a case-insensitive attribute selector in xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

What I have:

`<xsl:param name="data_value_loadtime" select="substring-before(value[@channel='Loading Time'],' m')" />`

What I need:
The 'Loading Time' appearance differs in each input document - it may be 'Loading Time', 'Loading time' or 'loading time'.

How can I make the selection ?

I've tried to apply `value[translate(@channel,'abcd...','ABCD...')='loading time'` but it hits me with an Invalid Token exception.

Please keep in mind that I'm bound to xslt 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In XSLT 1.0 you need**:

```
<xsl:param name="data_value_loadtime" select=
"substring-before(value[translate(@channel, 'LOADING TIME', 'loading time') 
                       =
                       'loading time'
                       ]
                   ,' m'
                  )" />
```